# Get all records from db from a specific datetime

Tags: c#, linq

I have a query that I use to retrieve all records from the database from a specific date that a user enters on the client page.

The goal is that when the user enters the date on the client side, then the server must retrieve all data  (from RentPeriod table) from the specific date and in the future.

My code looks like this:

```
  DateTime realStartTime = Convert.ToDateTime(startTime);                      
                   var parkingspot = from Address in _parkShareDbContext.Addresses.Where(a => a.Active == true)
                   join ParkingSpot in _parkShareDbContext.ParkingSpots.Where(p => p.Active == true).Where(p => size == null || p.Spotsize == size) on Address.Id equals ParkingSpot.Address.Id
                   join RentPeriod in _parkShareDbContext.RentPeriods.Where(rp => rp.Type == periodType && rp.IsRentedOut == false).Where(rp => realStartTime >= rp.RentPeriodStart) on ParkingSpot.Id equals RentPeriod.ParkingSpotId
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you better map this to a parameterized sql statement as your performance will become problematic when you have more records in your database

Comment: What is the question/problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to end your query with a select clause - and I think your rent period start time comparison is the wrong way round, unless I've misunderstood you - but I would also convert your whole query into the query syntax rather than the mix you have, e.g.

```cs
var parkingspot = from Address in _parkShareDbContext.Addresses
                  join ParkingSpot in _parkShareDbContext.ParkingSpots on Address.Id equals ParkingSpot.Address.Id
                  join RentPeriod in _parkShareDbContext.RentPeriods on ParkingSpot.Id equals RentPeriod.ParkingSpotId
                  where ParkingSpot.Active 
                  && (size == null || ParkingSpot.Spotsize == size)
                  && RentPeriod.Type == periodType
                  && !RentPeriod.IsRentedOut
                  && RentPeriod.RentPeriodStart >= realStartTime
                  select RentPeriod;
```

**EDIT**

However, as per the comments above, with complex queries like this one, you are usually better off writing a parameterised SQL query, or using a stored procedure to fetch data.

I'm also not sure why you need `Address` in there?

Comment: Hahahah, holy moly I'm dumb. I should just change the sign as you suggested. For some reason it was realStartTime >= rp.RentPeriodStart I thought was the right thing. 

That's the disadvantage of looking blindly at its code hehe

Comment: This is small query, don't even try to rewrite to SP. EF will create parametrized SQL automatically.

Comment: No problem, if it's helped please mark as answer ;-).